# How do I access files on a Mac OS X Server under Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, osx-server, afp

I'm trying to connect to a server at work which is run on a Mac but I have a PC (windows 7) at home.   I have path to connect in the format of afp://server.com/files.   Is there a client that I need to install on my PC that I can use to login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the usual Windows notation \\server.com\files

If it does not work, and if you have control over the server (can have the admins make changes), on the Mac to got System Preferences, Sharing, then click Options for the File Sharing entry in the list and there enable "SMB Sharing".  This will make the Mac share files in Windows style too.

Comment: This is correct; turn on SMB sharing, and the Mac will appear on the local network to your Windows machines like it was a Windows file server. Upvoted.

Comment: SMB sharing is what the OP needs, but he needs to be careful. Modifying any files on the server will destroy their resource forks. For most files it's not a problem, but for others (Type 1 Fonts, for example) it will damage the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the bad news is windows 7 may not have AFP support - [wikipedia explicitly mentions many pre-7 OSes having it, but that server 2008 does not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol) said article also lists clients for it as well.